# $.extend() with functions

Tags: jquery, plugins, extend

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that will need callback functions that are executed, for example, when an option is chosen from the `<select>` the plugin is applied to.

I've seen plugins that allow you to define functions in the options you pass it, like this:

```
$('div.foo').pluginBar({ 
    option1: 'red',
    someEvent: function() {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

I want to be able to define a default `someEvent` function in my plugin code, but if the user defines that function in the options they pass, it should overwrite the default function. Is this possible with `$.extend()`, or am I look in the wrong places?

I've had a look at the [plugin authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) tutorial, but I don't think it covers extending the default behaviour of *functions* anywhere. I've read things about using an `init:` function, but I'd rather just be able to define a function (*inside* the plugin namespace) and change it with the options passed to the plugin.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, was more of a personal frustration comment. Will remove.

Comment: In JavaScript (unlike most other major current languages), functions are first class objects. That means you can do the same thing with function references that you can do with any other kind of object reference, including this. The answers demonstrate how, but the key point to take away is that function references are values just like object references (because they *are* object references). It's hugely useful. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.pluginBar = function(options) {
      var settings = $.extend( {
          someEvent: function() {
              alert('default');
          }
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
          settings.someEvent();
      });
  };
})( jQuery );

$('div.foo').pluginBar({ 
    option1: 'red',
    someEvent: function() {
        alert('custom');
    }
});
```

If you don't specify `someEvent` when wiring up the plugin, the default one will be used.

Comment: Just figured something out, thought i'd share -- to have 'div.foo' available to the someEvent function, pass "this" without quotes as a parameter. Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/taytayevanson/LY3K7/

Answer (score 8):

In javascript, functions are first-class objects. Meaning, you can use functions like you would any other variable:

```
//making an anonymous function, and assigning it to a variable
var meep = function () {
    return 'meep';
};

//passing a function as a parameter
[ 'moop' ].map( meep ); //['meep']

//assigning it in an object literal
var weirdNoises = {
    'meep' : meep,

    'slarg' : function () {
        return 'slarg';
    }
};

weirdNoises.meep(); //'meep'
weirdNoises.slarg(); //'slarg'

//you can also return functions
function meeper () {
    return meep;
}
function slarger () {
    return function () {
        return 'slarg';
    };
}

//meeper returns a function, so the second () means "execute the function
// that was returned"
meeper()(); //'meep'
slarger()(); //'slarg'
```

As you can see, functions are just like any other value. So, you can define a default option that'll be a function, and override it like anything else.

```
$.fn.weirdNoise = function ( options ) {
    var defaults = {
        makeNoise : function () {
            return 'Rabadabadaba';
        },
        isSilly : true
    };

    return $.extend( defaults, options );
};

var raba = $( 'foobar' ).weirdNoise().makeNoise();
raba.makeNoise(); //'Rabadabadaba'
raba.isSilly; //true

var shaba = $( 'foobar' ).wierdNoise({
    makeNoise : function () {
        return 'Shabadabadoo';
    }
});
shaba.makeNoise(); //'Shabadabadoo'
shaba.isSilly; //true
```

A contrived example, but I think it illustrates the point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can extend objects that have function values.

```
var originalFunction = function() { 
    alert( 'original' );
}

var a = { 
    foo: 'bar', 
    func: originalFunction 
};

var b = { 
    foo: 'baz', 
    func: function() { 
        alert( 'ok' ); 
    } 
};

var c = $.extend( {}, a, b );

c.func();    // alerts 'ok'
```

In JavaScript there's often no practical difference between functions and other values, so you can treat functions as you would other objects or data types.